N DMA Transfers based on a timer trigger using stm32F429I
I'm trying to use timer 8, stm32f429I, as advanced timer, to do N DMA transfers, that copies data from port D to memory and it does trigger on PC6 after triggering, an N DMA transfers should be shot I have tried, but now it triggers only DMA transfer, only one PC6 falling edge but it doesn't do N repetition If I set repetition counter to N, the trigger is not working any more
static void MX_DMA_Init(void)

{
/* DMA controller clock enable */
 __HAL_RCC_DMA2_CLK_ENABLE();

 HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA2_Stream7_IRQn, 0, 0);

 HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA2_Stream7_IRQn);

}
static void MX_TIM8_Init(void)
{

TIM_ClockConfigTypeDef sClockSourceConfig = {0};
TIM_SlaveConfigTypeDef sSlaveConfig = {0};
TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig = {0};

 htim8.Instance = TIM8;
 htim8.Init.Prescaler = 0;
 htim8.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
 htim8.Init.Period = 65535;
 htim8.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
 htim8.Init.RepetitionCounter = 0;
 htim8.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;

if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim8) != HAL_OK)
 {
 Error_Handler();
 }
 sClockSourceConfig.ClockSource = TIM_CLOCKSOURCE_INTERNAL;

if (HAL_TIM_ConfigClockSource(&htim8, &sClockSourceConfig) != HAL_OK)
 {
 Error_Handler();
 }
 sSlaveConfig.SlaveMode = TIM_SLAVEMODE_TRIGGER;
 sSlaveConfig.InputTrigger = TIM_TS_TI1FP1;
 sSlaveConfig.TriggerPolarity = TIM_TRIGGERPOLARITY_FALLING;
 sSlaveConfig.TriggerFilter = 0;

if (HAL_TIM_SlaveConfigSynchro(&htim8, &sSlaveConfig) != HAL_OK)
 {
 Error_Handler();

 }
 sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
 sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim8, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
 {

 Error_Handler();

 }
}

void HAL_TIM_Base_MspInit(TIM_HandleTypeDef* htim_base)
{
GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};

if(htim_base->Instance==TIM8)
{
 __HAL_RCC_TIM8_CLK_ENABLE();
 __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();

/**TIM8 GPIO Configuration

 PC6 ------> TIM8_CH1
 */
 GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_6;
 GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
 GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
 GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
 GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF3_TIM8;
 HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStruct);
/* TIM8 DMA Init */
/* TIM8_CH4_TRIG_COM Init */
 hdma_tim8_ch4_trig_com.Instance = DMA2_Stream7;
 hdma_tim8_ch4_trig_com.Init.Channel = DMA_CHANNEL_7;
 hdma_tim8_ch4_trig_com.Init.Direction = DMA_PERIPH_TO_MEMORY;
 hdma_tim8_ch4_trig_com.Init.PeriphInc = DMA_PINC_DISABLE;
 hdma_tim8_ch4_trig_com.Init.MemInc = DMA_MINC_ENABLE;
 hdma_tim8_ch4_trig_com.Init.PeriphDataAlignment = DMA_PDATAALIGN_HALFWORD;
 hdma_tim8_ch4_trig_com.Init.MemDataAlignment = DMA_MDATAALIGN_HALFWORD;
 hdma_tim8_ch4_trig_com.Init.Mode = DMA_NORMAL;
 hdma_tim8_ch4_trig_com.Init.Priority = DMA_PRIORITY_HIGH;
 hdma_tim8_ch4_trig_com.Init.FIFOMode = DMA_FIFOMODE_DISABLE;
if (HAL_DMA_Init(&hdma_tim8_ch4_trig_com) != HAL_OK)
 {
 Error_Handler();
 }
//__HAL_LINKDMA(htim_base,hdma[TIM_DMA_ID_CC4],hdma_tim8_ch4_trig_com);
 __HAL_LINKDMA(htim_base,hdma[TIM_DMA_ID_TRIGGER],hdma_tim8_ch4_trig_com);
//__HAL_LINKDMA(htim_base,hdma[TIM_DMA_ID_COMMUTATION],hdma_tim8_ch4_trig_com);
HAL_DMA_RegisterCallback(&hdma_tim8_ch4_trig_com,HAL_DMA_XFER_CPLT_CB_ID,HAL_DMA_TransferComplete);

 HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(TIM8_TRG_COM_TIM14_IRQn, 0, 0);
 HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(TIM8_TRG_COM_TIM14_IRQn);
 HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(TIM8_UP_TIM13_IRQn, 0, 0);
 HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(TIM8_UP_TIM13_IRQn);
 }
}

void TIM8_TRG_COM_TIM14_IRQHandler(void)
{

HAL_TIM_IRQHandler(&htim8);

}

void TIM8_Update_Callback(void) {


 HAL_DMA_Start_IT(&hdma_tim8_ch4_trig_com,(uint32_t)&(GPIOD->IDR),(uint32_t)current_dma_buffer,sizeof(current_dma_buffer));


}

void DMA2_Stream7_IRQHandler(void)

{

 HAL_DMA_IRQHandler(&hdma_tim8_ch4_trig_com);


}

Before main loop:
__HAL_TIM_ENABLE_IT(&htim8, TIM_IT_TRIGGER);
/* Enable the TIMX OC channel */
TIM_CCxChannelCmd(htim8.Instance, TIMx_CHANNEL_OC, TIM_CCx_ENABLE);

/* Enable the TIMx IC channel */
TIM_CCxChannelCmd(htim8.Instance, TIMx_CHANNEL_IC, TIM_CCx_ENABLE);


__HAL_TIM_ENABLE_DMA(&htim8, TIM_DMA_TRIGGER);
__HAL_TIM_ENABLE_DMA(&htim8, TIM_DMA_CC4);


For me HAL is good if you want to do some simple. If you need more complicated setup I always use bare registers as I know what is happening which is not the case when you use HAL
